# Redirect to profile url after login

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, routes

I am new in backend Node.js and till now I am able to complete registration and login with authentication.

When login I am getting token in response by using jwt token

Now I want to have the registration details to be shown to users after login. After login the details must of be of particular user's only whos is logging in.

And if admin is logging in, then he will get the entire database user's fields.

This is my **index.route:-**

```
const express = require ('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const ctrlUser = require ('../controllers/user.controller.js');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const passport = require('passport');

// routing functions 
//registartion user signup
router.post('/register' , ctrlUser.register);

//login user
router.post('/login' , (req, res, next) => {

    User.find({email: req.body.email})
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
        if(user.length < 1) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed. User not found."
            })
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) =>{
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed. Check email and password"
                });             
            }   
            if (result){
             const adminEmail = "rohit@metapercept.com";                                                
             const role = user[0].email===adminEmail? "admin" : "user";                                 //check user id as admin or user
            const token = jwt.sign( 
                {
                    email: user[0].email,
                    userId: user[0]._id,
                    role
                },
                process.env.JWT_KEY,
                {
                    expiresIn : "1h"
                });
                return res.status(200).json({
                message: "Auth Successful",
                token : token
                });
                res.redirect('/profile');
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        if (err.code == 500)
                    res.status(500).send(["Something went wrong in login"]);
            else
            return next(err);
    });
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next){
  //something todo here ... 
});

//delete user 
router.delete('/:userId' , (req, res, next) =>{

    User.deleteMany({_id: req.params.userId})
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).send(["Deleted"]);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        if (err.code == 500)
                    res.status(500).send(["Didn't get deleted"]);
            else
            return next(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

*How can I access user's details in profile url API?*

Answer (score 0):

Get JWT from request header then decode

```
  jwt.verify(token, getKey, options, function(err, decoded) {
  console.log(decoded.email)
});
```

[jwt.verify - jwt doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

Answer (score 0):

Create new middleware **( above other routes)**

```
// route middleware to verify a token
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  // decode token
  if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {       if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });       } else {
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        req.decoded = decoded;         next();
      }
    });

  } else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.' 
    });

  }
});
```

Help : [jwt - decode and save in req](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens#toc-route-middleware-to-protect-api-routes)

Comment: And in `/profile`, access to your user's infos with req.decoded

Comment: Now , I am getting this forbidden message in /login `{
    "success": false,
    "message": "No token provided."
}` . This must not happen in login.

Comment: That means it is getting applicable to all the POST  json body token route. Something is wrong

Comment: try to change routes name : 
- /profile -> /user/profile 
- /:userId -> /user/:userId

middleware : 
app.use(function() ...) -> app.use('/user', function() ...)

Comment: can't I already have a root endpoint in my main`app.js` ie; `app.use('/api', rtsIndex);`  and besides i have separate file to verify token .

Answer (score 0):

In the code, After `return` your `redirect` never work. so There're 2 options:

1. You don't need to return a token to client, just use `res.redirect('/profile')` after your verification. (in this way, your server and client are in one)
2. You just return the token to client (Don't use `res.redirect('/profile')` anymore) then client will use that token to redirect to the profile. (in this way, your server and client are separate each other).

Comment: Ok ,for 2nd option , what is the way to use that token for profile route ?

Comment: For 2nd option, You should set the profile route in client side. Then after your login verification is done from server. Your client will take that result to authenticate in the client and use that token for the next request to server.

Comment: To authenticate in the client. one of simple way is. you can create a global boolean variable call `isAuthenticated` and set default by `False`. After your login success and you receive a good result from server you can change it  to `True`. Then Your client is already authenticated.

Comment: When login with valid user , I am getting token . That means it is authenticated ? `{
    "message": "Auth Successful",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InJvaGl0QG1ldGFwZXJjZXB0LmNvbSIsInVzZXJJZCI6IjVjMmRlZTE3ZWFkNDQyNjRhNDAxNTZmMCIsInJvbGUiTAwMiwiZXhwIjoxNTQ2ODQ4NjAyfQ.PZ5_rthEs5dYVoEVcwhkR64OlfDlRdpqKTu3fRpDq00"
}`

Comment: Yes, then save that token in client side for the next request to server. I suppose that all your route in server is secure (that mean, everyone must login to get the token, then use that token to access into another route). e.g: you wanna get more info about your account. So from client you send a request with your token to `'/profile'` in server to get content. then show up that content to your client view.

Comment: Exactly, I am not getting how to use the token into another route.